a most likely incorrect identity involving the riemann zeta function
Consider:
$$I(s)=2\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \int_{J=(0,n^{-s/2})} e^{\frac{\log^2({n^{s/2}})}{\log t}}~dt$$
for $\Re(s)>0$.
Split $I(s)$ into the following components:
$$ I(s)=\zeta(s)+s\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \log n~K_1(s\log n). $$
We can write this as: $$ I(s)=\zeta(s)+sf(s)$$
where: $$f(s)=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \log n~K_1(s\log n)$$
for convergence of $f(s)$ on $\Re(s)>0$.
Moving $\zeta(s)$ to the LHS of the equation, we obtain:
$$ sf(s)=I(s)-\zeta(s). $$
We assume $sf(s)$ is invertible by integrating over some region of the complex plane $\Bbb C$.
We take, and verify the following ansatz:
$$ \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} \int_{I=(0,1)} e^{\frac{\frac{s^2}{4}\cdot~\log^2(n)}{\log t}}~dt =sf(s). $$
This should imply that:
$$2\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} e^{\frac{\log^2({n^{s/2}})}{\log t}}-\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} e^{\frac{\frac{s^2}{4}\cdot~\log^2(n)}{\log t}}=\mathcal M^{-1} \zeta(s)$$
at least for $\Re(s)>0$.
Therefore we recover the identity:
$$ \mathcal M^{-1}\zeta(s)=\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} e^{\frac{\frac{s^2}{4}\cdot~\log^2(n)}{\log t}}.\tag{1}$$
But we note that the notation $\mathcal M^{-1}$ does not denote the standard Mellin transform and we also note that it is not clear which path in $\Bbb C$ gives this result. Furthermore, it is possible that we are dealing with non-invertible transform.

Is there a way to interpret the identity $(1)$? How can we find the specific path to integrate over in the complex plane to achieve this? I'm a little uneasy about $s$ appearing on both the LHS and RHS.

Thanks for any feedback and corrections.
Proof without words to give some visual intuition for what's going on:

